# How to re-render content of Modal

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am using the content property of MUI Dialog.

But, when I change the state on the parent component, the content modal is not re-render.

I expect when I change the state on the parent component, the content component is re-rendered.
How can I fix it?

Following this https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-lucy-79mgg1

After making Modifying in below components, the fileCount on UploadModal not updating as the component not re-rendered. as I am achiving dynamic component to be rendered in modal as props coming from parent components.

Can any help me with this. Thanks a advance

```
const Home = () => {
    const { modal, openModal } = useModal();
    const { fileCount, setFileCount} = useState(0);

    const uploadFile = (file) => {
        // make some req to some endpoint
        setFileCount(fileCount+1)
        console.log("File uploaded");
    };

    return (
        <Stack>
            <Typography>Home</Typography>
            <Button
                onClick={() =>
                    openModal("UploadModal", { title: "avatar", uploadFile, fileCount })
                }
                variant="contained"
            >
                Upload avatar
            </Button>
        </Stack>
    );

}
```

```
//UploadModal.js
const UploadModal = ({ onClose, title, uploadFile, fileCount }) => {
    return (
        <Dialog open fullWidth onClose={onClose}>
            <Stack p={3}>
                <Typography>Upload {title} </Typography>
                <Typography>File count {fileCount } </Typography>
                <Button onClick={uploadFile} variant="contained">
                  Upload
                </Button>
            </Stack>
        </Dialog>
    );
};
```

Comment: just try changing this line `const { fileCount, setFileCount} = useState(0);` with square brackets like this  `const [ fileCount, setFileCount ]= useState(0);` and see if it works.

Comment: https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#tip-what-do-square-brackets-mean

Comment: Tried but not working.